# Upload file using C# selenium without SendKeys

Tags: c#, selenium, upload

I want to upload a file using Selenium Webdriver with C#, but the SendKeys doesn´t work in my case, because the HTML does not have the input type="file"

I can click on the "button" and the explorer open correctly, but after that I couldn´t do anything.
Here is the part of HTML area to click:

```
<div class="row drop-box cotacao-estudo" ngf-drop="vm.UploadFiles($files, vm.TipoDocumentoEnum.ESTUDO)" ngf-select="vm.UploadFiles($files, vm.TipoDocumentoEnum.ESTUDO)" ngf-change="vm.ValidateFiles($files, $file, $newFiles, $duplicateFiles, $invalidFiles, $event, vm.TipoDocumentoEnum.ESTUDO)" ngf-max-size="30MB" ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-allow-dir="true" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/tiff,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,image/png,application/pdf,text/plain,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/msword" ngf-pattern="'image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/tiff,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,image/png,application/pdf,text/plain,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/msword'">
    <i class="fa fa-folder fa-3x pull-left" style="color:#5bc0de" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <label class="pull-left">Estudo *</label>
    <span class="pull-left">Clique para selecionar ou arraste os arquivos aqui</span>
    <div class="progress pull-left ng-hide" ng-show="vm.progressEstudo > 0">
        <div style="width:%;" ng-bind="vm.progressEstudo + '%'" class="ng-binding">%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code of the click:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//fieldset[@class='ng-scope']/div[1]/i")).Click();
```

OR

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("cotacao-estudo")).Click();
```

I´ve already tried this code without success:

```
//string filePath = @"C:\Users\cccarvalho\Documents\AUTOMACOES\Estudo.pdf";

String caminho = "//fieldset[@class='ng-scope']/div[1]/i";

document.evaluate('caminho', document, null, 
XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

String script = "driver.getElementByXpath('caminho').value='" + 
"C:\\\\file.txt" + "';";


((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
```

Comment: After clicking on upload button, is windows explorer opening ?

Comment: Can you check the dom and see if you can find an `input` tag with `type="file"` that is hidden either by setting the `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` css property?

Comment: @SaiPawan yes, win explorer appear on click.

Comment: @GPT14 no, there isn´t any hidden elements/tags

Comment: Run `$$("input[type='file']")` in the dev console. My guess is that it's there, it's just not visible.

Comment: @SaiPawan, it works with yout code, many Thanks!!!!!!!!
   `SendKeys.SendWait(@"Path"); SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");`

Comment: Can you try what @JeffC has suggested in his comment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After explorer is opened you can send the path of the file as below.

```
SendKeys.SendWait(@"Path of file");

SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```

Comment: u have to use "using System.Windows;"

Comment: Before downvoting the answer please provide a valid reason too

Comment: Send keys is going to make your test fail as soon as the browser window is not in focus. Meaning if the window is minimised, partially or fully covered by some other window, your target window is never going to get the file path or the enter key.

Comment: Yes that will work for opened explorer popup.To upload any file using explorer we have to use Sendkeys or actions class.One more alternative is automating explorer using autoit.